# jQuery complex Validation rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to specify some rules dynamically on a form. On this form I have three TextBox input (`Text1`, `Text2`, `Text3`) and a checkbox (`Check1`)

I shall configure the following rules:

1. Rule for `Text2`: The field shall be a positive number with 2 decimal digits and it's value shall be equal or greater than `Text1`
2. Rule for `Text3`: The field shall be a number with 2 decimal digits. Moreover:

   a) The value of `Text3` has to be equal to zero if `Check1` is selected

   b) The value of `Text3` must be smaller or equal to `Text1` and smaller or equal to `Text2` if `Check1` is not selected.

How can I express those rules within the [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin? Any advice?

**UPDATE**:
This is the basic rule for (1). It misses the *equal or greather* part:

```
$('#Text2').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    min: 0.0,
    number: true,
    messages: {
        required: 'Message 1',
        min: 'Message 2',
        number: 'Message 3'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of $.validator.addMethod..

for example,

```
$.validator.addMethod("decimal", function(val, element){return /\d*(\.\d+)?/.test(val)}, "Should enter only numericals.");
```

the above method just check for decimal.

We can use this by adding the first parameter name in the class name such as

```
<input type="text" class="required decimal" />
```

In your case, you need to check for whether the value is greater than text1, so we can do it as

```
$.validator.addMethod("text2validator", function(val, element){if(val > $("#text1").val())return true;}, "Value should be greater than text1")

<input type="text" id="text1" value="10" />
<input type="text" id="text2" class="required decimal text2validator" />
```